# Pandas: Apply filter for specific rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am having a df where one of the column has dict values. i would like to parse information and store in new/same column.
i am currently doing it like below

```
data = [{'objtype': 'dict', 'objval': '{"name":"adam"}'}, {'objtype': 'dict', 'objval': '{"name":"eve"}'}, {'objtype': 'dict', 'objval': '{"name":"krishna"}'}, {'objtype': 'dict', 'objval': '{"name":"radha"}'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['extract'] = df['objval'].apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(lambda x: x.get('name'))
```

this breaks for below example

```
[{'objtype': 'text', 'objval': 'adam'}, {'objtype': 'text', 'objval': 'eve'}, {'objtype': 'dict', 'objval': '{"name":"krishna"}'}, {'objtype': 'dict', 'objval': '{"name":"radha"}'}]
```

i would like apply filter something like below

```
df['extract'] = df['objval'].apply(ast.literal_eval if df['objtype'] == 'dict')
```

Additionaly:
end result should have names stored in new column regardless of objtype being text/dict.

`df['extract'] = df['objval'].apply(ast.literal_eval if df['objtype'] == 'dict')`
this statement is assuming that whereevet objtype is dict value will also be a dict.
i would also want to change this so that it relies on the data itself

something like
`df['extract'] = df['objval'].apply(ast.literal_eval if type(df['objval']) == 'dict')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try..except` to catch `ValueError` exception thrown by `ast.literal_eval`:

```py
import ast


def get_name(x):
    try:
        x = ast.literal_eval(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x
    return x.get("name")


data = [
    {"objtype": "text", "objval": "adam"},
    {"objtype": "text", "objval": "eve"},
    {"objtype": "dict", "objval": '{"name":"krishna"}'},
    {"objtype": "dict", "objval": '{"name":"radha"}'},
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["extract"] = df["objval"].apply(get_name)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  objtype              objval  extract
0    text                adam     adam
1    text                 eve      eve
2    dict  {"name":"krishna"}  krishna
3    dict    {"name":"radha"}    radha
```

Comment: i am also looking to get multiple values from the dict. is possible to parameterize get_name(x,filename) and then apply to df

Comment: @rakesh Can you edit your question and put there sample input (with multiple values in dict) end expected output?

Comment: i was able to figure it. passed argument as kwarg. thanks for guiding.  -->df["extract"] = df["objval"].apply(get_name,fieldname = 'name')

Answer (score 0):

One way using `yaml.safe_load` to handle the dict, dict-like str, str, etc.:

```
df["objval"].apply(yaml.safe_load).str["name"]
```

Output:

```
0        NaN
1        NaN
2    krishna
3      radha
Name: objval, dtype: object
```